# How can I edit a view using phpMyAdmin 3.2.4?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I need to simply edit a very complicated view in phpMyAdmin 3.2.4 but I cannot figure how to do that. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 232):

To expand one what CheeseConQueso is saying, here are the entire steps to update a view using PHPMyAdmin:

1. Run the following query: `SHOW CREATE VIEW your_view_name`
2. Expand the options and choose ***Full Texts***
3. Press ***Go***
4. Copy entire contents of the ***Create View*** column.
5. Make changes to the query in the editor of your choice
6. Run the query directly (without the `CREATE VIEW`... syntax) to make sure it runs as you expect it to.
7. Once you're satisfied, click on your view in the list on the left to browse its data and then scroll all the way to the bottom where you'll see a ***CREATE VIEW*** link. Click that.
8. Place a check in the ***OR REPLACE*** field.
9. In the ***VIEW name*** put the name of the view you are going to update.
10. In the ***AS*** field put the contents of the query that you ran while testing (without the `CREATE VIEW...` syntax).
11. Press **Go**

Special thanks to CheesConQueso for their insightful answer.

Comment: Who so ever looking at this answer, please update the `phpMyAdmin` to version `4.9.0.1`, it includes the bug fix for that edit view thing.

Answer (score 64):

In your database table list it should show View in Type column.
To edit View:

1. Click on your View in table list
2. Click on Structure tab
3. Click on Edit View under Check All

[image]

Hope this help

**update:** in PHPMyAdmin 4.x, it doesn't show View in Type, but you can still recognize it:

1. In Row column: It had zero Row
2. In Action column: It had greyed empty button

Of course it may be just an empty table, but when you open the structure, you will know whether it's a table or a view.

Comment: When I do this, I can't "edit" the view, but only replace it with a "new" view, starting from scratch.

Comment: Same here, getting a window with "new" view. Not seeing any SQL-code.

Comment: Don't have "Edit View" in my version, which was confusing...

Answer (score 47):

try running `SHOW CREATE VIEW my_view_name` in the sql portion of phpmyadmin and you will have a better idea of what is inside the view

Comment: maybe you could create a new view based upon the result of the command above and add your edits to it?

Answer (score 11):

Just export you view and you will have all SQL need to make some change on it.

Just need to add your change in SQL query for the view and change :

**CREATE** for **CREATE OR REPLACE**

Answer (score 0):

Select your view in *Bookmarked SQL query* section then select *Delete* then click *Go* button.
[image]