# How can I see the Original MySQL used to create a view in phpMyAdmin or other program?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, sql-view

How can I see the *original* MySQL used to create a view in phpMyAdmin or other program?

I am using phpMyAdmin version 3.3.9.

This post tells how to see the SQL used to create a view but its not the original SQL used.
[How can I edit a view using phpMyAdmin 3.2.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279240/how-can-i-edit-a-view-using-phpmyadmin-3-2-4)

The code returned works, it just doesn't have my original format making it harder to edit. Is there a program to make this easier or do I need to save my original SQL in a text file somewhere?

### Example:

**SQL Used:**

```
CREATE VIEW `wheel`.`new_view` AS
SELECT
`t_ci_sessions`.`session_id`,
`t_ci_sessions`.`ip_address`,
`t_ci_sessions`.`user_agent`,
`t_ci_sessions`.`last_activity`,
`t_ci_sessions`.`user_data`
FROM `wheel`.`t_ci_sessions`;
SELECT * FROM `wheel`.`ci_sessions`;
```

**SQL phpMyAdmin Returns:**

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `new_view` AS select `t_ci_sessions`.`session_id` AS `session_id`,`t_ci_sessions`.`ip_address` AS `ip_address`,`t_ci_sessions`.`user_agent` AS `user_agent`,`t_ci_sessions`.`last_activity` AS `last_activity`,`t_ci_sessions`.`user_data` AS `user_data` from `t_ci_sessions`
```

Comment: similar one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279240/how-can-i-edit-a-view-using-phpmyadmin-3-2-4

Comment: It is kinda hidden, but I did post that link in my description. I was wondering if there was a way to view the Original Formatted SQL used to create the view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't find out the exact SQL used to create a view, but you can see the *parsed* version of it, which will of course be very close and semantically exactly the same, using this command:

```
show create view my_view_name;
```

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, I guess its not that bad. I'll just save my originals to a text file for easy access.

Comment: Or perhaps save them in a table `sql_queries` to keep them all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Information schema have the definition of the views:

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'viewName'
```