# How to update a view in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, view, phpmyadmin

How can I update (or edit) a View in MySQL database using phpMyAdmin.

I got a view that's made of columns from two tables - I added a new column to one of these, but the view doesn't have it. I can't find the MySQL query I used to get this view (it's quite obscure one) - so how can I edit the MySQL query that created this view to add a new column into it?

Comment: No. It just displays something like `SELECT * FROM View`.

Comment: @F4r-20 - you don't understand. It does not display all columns from the source table. The query it shows relates to the view, not source tables. You know how views work?

Comment: Oh I see now, OK my bad I was on the wrong tracks there.

Comment: Duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279240/how-can-i-edit-a-view-using-phpmyadmin-3-2-4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about using  (Your view is called viewname)

1. `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname` to get the SQL for the view as it is
2. `DROP VIEW viewname` to remove the view
3. Modify the SQL from the first step to add the new column to that SQL
4. Run the modified SQL

That would create the view with the additional column(s)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-view.html

Comment: `SHOW CREATE VIEW` displays only `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=root@localho...` (note "..." - it doesn't display full result) <- nothing useful.

Comment: Sound like phpMyAdmin is not showing you the entire query results.  You can try to export the query as @user1681542 mentioned in their answer to get the SQL then do steps 2-4 above.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin are you using?

Comment: On the Query Result page you should see an options button/link (I have it on 3.5.7) - click that to get a "Full texts" option vs. " Partial texts".  That should get you the entire SQL result text not just the truncated version you currently see.

Comment: Note, that you don't have to DROP the view first. If you want to update it you can always run CREATE OR REPLACE (or click the "Or replace" checkbox in phpmyadmin).

Answer (score 3):

To take the view for edit/update,we have used two way:

```
Step 1: 

select your view in phpmyadmin and click Export(make sure click check box of Structure& Add DROP VIEW) & GO.you'll see a CREATE VIEW  query like as:CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`dbname`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_name` AS select ..etc..And then remove 'ALGORITHM.....to...DEFINER' part from this query and update/added required field/make changes to the query.and then execute modified view.`


step 2:

    Run the query: SHOW CREATE VIEW `vw_name`
    Expand the result and choose Full Texts.        
    Copy entire contents of the Create View column.
    Make changes to the query.
    Run the query directly (with out the CREATE VIEW... syntax) to make sure it runs as you expect it to.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`, to avoid the step of dropping the view:

- `show create view viewname`. Find definition in 'Create View' column
- use below command to add new columns: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`

Answer (score 2):

**A Simpler Way**

Most of the time, not being able to edit views etc. is due to the DEFINER being set to root@localhost, and if you're coming from a web host control panel, that user is not you.

1. Click Home (house icon) top left, copy your username to the right.
2. Click your view on the left > Structure > Edit View and edit.
3. Paste your username in place of 'root@localhost' and click Go.

*This has been tested on PHPMyAdmin 4.9.0.1, it may also work on earlier and later versions. PHPMyAdmin seems to remember your username for the rest of the session, so that you can edit freely.*

Answer (score 1):

On phpMyADmin Go to Export -> (select) 'Quick - display only the minimal options' -> GO.

That will give you the create statements that you made in a text file, view or save that text file and you should have all the info there.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a very old question, but I think this will be helpful to many people as I faced this difficulty finding the Views SQL query.

I'm using `Version information: 4.9.11` of `phpMyAdmin` and you can find views query in `Structure` section of the view and there is `Edit View` button under the columns. For better visibility here is screenshot of it:

[image]

After this, you can modify your query to show multiple columns in your view.

Comment: Always happy to see additional answers for an older questions :) Cheers, thank you for that :)